# Samsung Galaxy S4 vibration

Tags: android, samsung-mobile

I am having problems with the new Samsung Galaxy S4.
It seems like audiomanager.setRingerMode();  doesn't work properly for notifications. It behaves crazy muting sounds or other strange things.
Any help with this?
Anybody else with same issue?

Thanks

Comment: Hi Ton, were you able to find any solution or workaround for this? Thanks!

Comment: Nope, sorry. What I found out is that some S4 releases came with an error. If you use aoudiomanager and vibration then the built-in Text/Sms app will not play or vibrate when incoming messages. I had to add a tick in my app, something like "Galaxy S4 mode". In this case I listen for incoming SMSs and I make it vibrate and play on my own. With third party apps like Handcent SMS or SMS Pro it works so it is just a built-in SMS app error.

Answer (score 0):

Change the Vibration Module or the Usb Module and you'll resolve this issue.. This is the only method.
I've got the same issue.
i've changed also the usb module because there was an issue of speaker too.

That components has got a low price.